# Getting reactive form values in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, angular4-forms

I am using reactive form in my Ionic project. 
I have multiple slides and each slide has a form. When i'm trying to retrieve the value I'm getting the value from the first slide.

Stackblitz link for the same https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zua1ss?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: provide the demo in stackblitz if possible .

Comment: if `quiz` in `[data]=quiz` is an `object`, it will reflect any changes made in the components as it is just an object reference. If you wanted to get the data from `quizData.quizzes`

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zua1ss?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Will get back to you . @daemon

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama any update?

Comment: I am middle of project. @daemon .